# Searching 2 fields at the same time

Tags: database, mysql

I have a table of first and last names

```
firstname    lastname
---------    ---------
Joe          Robertson
Sally        Robert
Jim          Green
Sandra       Jordan
```

I'm trying to search this table based on an input that consists of the full name. For example:

```
input: Joe Robert
```

I thought about using

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE firstname LIKE
```

BUT the table stores the first and last name separately, so I'm not sure how to do the search in this case

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `MyISAM`:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    mytable
WHERE   MATCH(firstname, lastname) AGAINST ("Joe* Robert*" IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

This will run much faster if you create a `FULLTEXT` index:

```
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ON mytable (firstname, lastname)
```

For the query to be able to search the short names (like `Joe` in your case), you'll need to set the variable `@@ft_min_word_len` to `1` before creating the index.

In `InnoDB` you'll need to split the search string:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    mytable
WHERE   firstname LIKE 'Joe%'
        AND lastname LIKE 'Robert%'
```

Comment: running a query in boolean mode without a full text search is slow so i would not recommend that.
and modifying server variables like '@@ft_min_word_len' is not ideal cz most of the time you cannot edit the mysql config file.

The simplest would be the query you have mentioned using like and wildcard

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to Quassnoi's method:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    mytable
WHERE   CONCAT(firstname, " ", lastname) = "Joe Robert"
```

Comment: It will be terribly slow but it should work. You may want to use single quotes in the query.

Comment: For exact match semantics, it is not slower than the fulltext query without the index. But it seems that the @op wants partial matches and this query won't match names like `Joel Robertson`